# How to split text value on comma?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

### How to split a text value on comma, to get two datapoints from it?

---

My code:

```
details = response.xpath('//div[@class="article-info"]')
for detail in details:
    body = detail.xpath('.//ul/li[1]/span[2]/span/text()').get()
    item['body'] = released
    yield item
```

My output:

> 293g (Wi-Fi) / 297g (Wi-Fi + Cellular), 6.3mm thickness

---

**Desired output (Column A) | Weight**

> 293g (Wi-Fi) / 297g (Wi-Fi + Cellular)

**Desired output (Column B) | Dimensions**

> 6.3mm

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.split()` takes an argument, so you can do this `.split(", ")` and unpack to `weight` and `thickness`.

Try this:

```py
details = response.xpath('//div[@class="article-info"]')
for detail in details:
    weight, thickness = detail.xpath('.//ul/li[1]/span[2]/span/text()').get().split(", ")
    item['weight'] = weight
    item['thickness'] = thickness.split()[0] # gets you 6.3mm only
    yield item
```

Comment: Split on `,` and check if the list has three items and decided what to do with such cases.